# Require_once messing with JSON encoding

Tags: php, ajax

I'm using AJAX to trigger my validation.php file. I want to connect to my database in that file, so I included connect.php file but it's causing some problem.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#offer-form").submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        $.ajax({
            type : 'POST',
            data: {
                'name': $('#name-input').val()
            },
            url : 'validation.php',
            success : function(data) {
                $("#name-error").text(data["name-error"]);
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
})
```

validation.php

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/json');

$error = array("name-error" => "");

require_once "connect.php";

$error['name-error'] = "error";

echo json_encode($error);
?>
```

connect.php

```
<?php 
$serverName = "localhost";
$dbName = "test";
$username = "root";
$password = "";

try 
{
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$serverName; dbname=$dbName",
                   $username,
                   $password, 
                   array(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false,
                         PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION)
                   );
    echo "Connected successfully"; 
}
catch (PDOException $e) 
{
    echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
}
?>
```

I simplified my code. The thing is that using *require_once* inside my validation.php file causes *name-error* no to be displayed. Another strange thing to me is that this file works when I type .../validation.php in my browser. I'm already using connect.php in my main file (one including script shown above) and it works fine.

Comment: Your response is not valid JSON

Comment: What do you mean?

Answer (score 2):

So this is what's happening:

Your browser will receive something like:

> This is a JSON response containing:

```
    Connected successfully
    {"name-error":"error"}
```

Or

```
    Connection failed: bla bla bla
    {"name-error":"error"}
```

In either case that's not valid JSON.

You can solve this in an alternative way:

**connection.php**

```
<?php 
$serverName = "localhost";
$dbName = "test";
$username = "root";
$password = "";


return new PDO("mysql:host=$serverName; dbname=$dbName",
                   $username,
                   $password, 
                   array(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false,
                         PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION)
                   );
```

**validation.php**

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/json');

try {
    $connection = require "connect.php"; //You can still set the variable in "connect.php" and use it here, but this shows intent better
    echo json_encode(array("name-error" => "There was no error");
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo json_encode(array("name-error" => $e->getMessage());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to tell the datatype for response

like this

```
   $.ajax({
        type : 'POST',
        data: {
            'name': $('#name-input').val()
        },
        url : 'validation.php',
        dataType: json,
        success : function(data) {
            $("#name-error").text(data["name-error"]);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Still doesn't work :( Don't know why, but setting up connection with database is messing up sending json response.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved! I found out that my php script was adding "\ufeff" before array in JSON response. All because I had my file encoding set to UTF-8 with BOM. Thanks everyone for help!